# How to prevent my application from end process by task manager?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have an application cafe timer. I want my application process not to end by task manager from users. Thanks

Comment: Is it through windows service only?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it as a Windows service with elevated credentials so that users have insufficient rights to end it.

You could bullet proof this by having your service auto restart on shutdown, and regularly saving some state into a data file so that you can carry on in case your service ever does get terminated.

Comment: Is this like antiviruses did?